# Detecting source of event and type of event using C#

Tags: c#

I'm learning how to work with delegates and by now have got some ideas. In a C# code (below) I like to capture type of event in string. What is the best approach to get the source of event and type of event?

For name of the source I'm using `sender.GetType().FullName.ToString();` if it is correct. What about event type?

Thanks.

```
protected virtual void OnChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    if (Changed != null)
        Changed(this,e);
}

protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnClosed(e);
    OnChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
}



public EventListener(myForm theform)
{
    TheForm = theform;
    TheForm.Changed += new ChangedEventHandler(myMethod);
}

private void myMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string s = "hey, got notified " + sender.GetType().FullName.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```

Comment: What are you calling the "event type"? The name of the `event`?

Comment: it is hard to give you answer, you gave a little info and it is not cleat what do you need...

Comment: @AdamRobinson yes that is what I meant.

Comment: so in notification method, I need to capture name of event and sender or let's say issuer of event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know which event call the function with the `EventArgs` class.

If you are using the prepared events (like Click event), you can create your own "Args" class like that:

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string EventCallerName { get; set; }
}
```

Then call the event like that:

```
 if (Changed != null)  
        Changed(this,new MyEventArgs() { EventCallerName = "Changed" });
```

And in the receiver method you can see that value, like that:

```
private void myMethod(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (e is MyEventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("Event type: " + (e as MyEventType).EventCallerName); 
    string s = "hey, got notified " + sender.GetType().FullName.ToString(); 
    MessageBox.Show(s); 
}
```

But, if you are using your own event you can create your own delegate and do with it whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the source of the event by using [a StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.getframe.aspx). I believe you'll find that events are usually fired by protected functions that have names that are similar to the event name.

Comment: Note that the StackTrace might not have all the frames you expect because of optimizations. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Backing type for events is delegate. The event source from the event handler cannot be determined. You however can check the delegate type when you are subscribing to the event. The class defining\publishing the event will be event source and type of delegate will be event type.

Answer (score 0):

May be that is right solution?:

```
        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var eventType = e.ToString().Split('.').Last().Replace("EventArgs", ""); //eventType = "FromClosed"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the name of the event, rather than detecting why don't you just fix it when you register the handler for the event? Something like:

```
public EventListener(myForm theform)
{
    TheForm = theform;
    TheForm.Changed += (s, e) => this.MyMethod(s, e, "Changed");
}

private void MyMethod(object sender, EventArgs e, string eventName)
{
    string s = "hey, got notified " + sender.GetType().FullName.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(s);
}
```